Terraform state file in different subscription: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account
I am working with Terraform in an Azure DevOps pipeline and I need to initialize Terraform with backend configuration parameters. Here is my Terraform configuration:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {}
  }

  backend "azurerm" {}
}

I want to pass the backend parameters like this in my Azure DevOps pipeline:
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "tf init"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        terraform init `
        -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}" `
        -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.storageAccountName }}" `
        -backend-config="container_name=${{ parameters.containerName }}" `
        -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.stateKey }}" `
        -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.stateSubscriptionId }}"

Before this step, I set the environment variables for Azure credentials:
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "set envs"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID = "{{ parameters.clientId }}"
        $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = "{{ parameters.clientSecret }}"
        $env:ARM_TENANT_ID = "{{ parameters.tenantId }}"
        $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "{{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}"

However, when I run terraform init, I get the following error:
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription(stateSubscriptionId) from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
│ 
│ 
╵

Attempting to log in with az login in service principal mode does not work, and results in this error:
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).
│ 
│ To authenticate to Azure using a Service Principal, you can use the separate 'Authenticate using a Service Principal' auth method - instructions for which can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret
│ 
│ Alternatively you can authenticate using the Azure CLI by using a User Account.
│ 
│ 
╵

Despite being logged into Azure CLI, I am still encountering this issue.
How can I log into a service principal for one subscription and have the state stored in another subscription in Azure Pipelines?
Any help would be appreciated!

Hi @michasaucer, have you declared environment variables with env: in every task that you need to use terraform to access Azure resource? Did it work for you?

I have the impression that the variables set in the set envs task will NOT be available to the other tasks.
Instead of:
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "Terraform init"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        terraform init `
        -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}" `
        -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.storageAccountName }}" `
        -backend-config="container_name=${{ parameters.containerName }}" `
        -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.stateKey }}" `
        -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.stateSubscriptionId }}"

Try setting the environment variables in each task that runs Terraform commands, such as terraform plan and terraform apply - example:
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "tf init"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        terraform init `
        -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}" `
        -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.storageAccountName }}" `
        -backend-config="container_name=${{ parameters.containerName }}" `
        -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.stateKey }}" `
        -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.stateSubscriptionId }}"
    env:
      ############################### remote state variables
      ARM_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.stateAccessKey }}
      ############################### azurerm provider authentication variables
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: {{ parameters.clientId }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: {{ parameters.clientSecret }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: {{ parameters.tenantId }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: {{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "tf plan"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        terraform plan ...
    env:
      ############################### remote state variables
      ARM_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.stateAccessKey }}
      ############################### azurerm provider authentication variables
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: {{ parameters.clientId }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: {{ parameters.clientSecret }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: {{ parameters.tenantId }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: {{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: "tf apply"
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        terraform apply ...
    env:
      ############################### remote state variables
      ARM_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ parameters.stateAccessKey }}
      ############################### azurerm provider authentication variables
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: {{ parameters.clientId }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: {{ parameters.clientSecret }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: {{ parameters.tenantId }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: {{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}

I've added the ARM_ACCESS_KEY to the environment variables, which might be required to authenticate to the remote state storage account.
In case you want to avoid repeating the environment variables in each task, consider creating a steps template to run terraform commands that require all the variables.

The environment variables you set in a PowerShell@2task are only valid in the current task. In the yaml below, the first PowerShell@2task defines two environment variables, and you can output their values in the first task. But when their values are output in the second task, the result is empty.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID = '${{ parameters.clientId }}'
        $env:ARM_TENANT_ID = '${{ parameters.tenantId }}'
        Write-Host The value of ARM_CLIENT_ID: $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID
        Write-Host The value of ARM_TENANT_ID: $env:ARM_TENANT_ID

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        Write-Host The value of ARM_CLIENT_ID: $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID
        Write-Host The value of ARM_TENANT_ID: $env:ARM_TENANT_ID


As mentioned by @Rui Jarimba, declare environment variables with env: in every task that you need to use terraform to access Azure resources.
- task: PowerShell@2
  env: 
    ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ parameters.clientId }}
    ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ parameters.clientSecret }}
    ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ parameters.tenantId }}
    ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ parameters.deploymentSubscriptionId }}
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      terraform init `
      -backend-config="resource_group_name=${{ parameters.resourceGroupName }}" `
      -backend-config="storage_account_name=${{ parameters.storageAccountName }}" `
      -backend-config="container_name=${{ parameters.containerName }}" `
      -backend-config="key=${{ parameters.stateKey }}" `
      -backend-config="subscription_id=${{ parameters.stateSubscriptionId }}"

